# Is the QuickBooks ListID unique across company files?

Tags: quickbooks

I'm using the Web Connector to fetch data from multiple company files, and I want to know whether storing the ListID of an Invoice will produce a unique identifier across company files, or if I need to also store in each record a reference to its company file to establish uniqueness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the QuickBooks ListID unique across company files?

No, it's not. It's a hexadecimal incrementing integer.

> if I need to also store in each record a reference to its company file to establish uniqueness.

Yes, you do need to do that.